# Unable to understand coffescript loops and comprehensions

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Can anybody explain this coffescript code

```
# Fine five course dining.
courses = ['greens', 'caviar', 'truffles', 'roast', 'cake']
menu i + 1, dish for dish, i in courses
```

What it will be compiled to in javascript with detailed explanations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because CoffeScript official site has a "Try CoffeScript" which already shows what code gets compiled into JavaScript just by copy-pasting current Q&A sample code: http://coffeescript.org/#try:courses%20%3D%20%5B'greens'%2C%20'caviar'%2C%20'truffles'%2C%20'roast'%2C%20'cake'%5D%0Amenu%20i%20%2B%201%2C%20dish%20for%20dish%2C%20i%20in%20courses

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer the website shows what it gets compiled to but there's not enough explanation for me to understand. Which is why I posted it here.

Comment: Sorry but I doubt it ;D

Comment: @MatiasFidermraizer  I did not have idea about postfix notation. deceze's answer helped. It can be someone else's query as well because people have asked question as following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263077/why-is-javascripts-postfix-notation-different-from-c-and-perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript allows you to write many statements in a postfix notation. Where traditionally you'd write

```
statement {
    code block
}
```

you can instead write:

```
code block statement
```

This makes it read more like English:

```
doSomething() if foo is 'bar'
```

Your loop isn't a comprehension, since you're not using the result as a value, it's merely the postfix notation for this:

```
for dish, i in courses
    menu i + 1, dish
```

I.e., execute the `menu` function with two arguments for each key/value in the array/object `courses`.

Comment: thanks for the answer.