# i++ doesn't work in ternary statement

Tags: javascript, ternary

Can someone explain to me why this statement won't work?

`i = (i >= 8 ? 1 : i++);`

yet this one does?

`i = (i >= 8 ? 1 : (i + 1));`

Comment: Because one never does `i = i++`

Comment: `i++` increments `i` and returns the *previous* value, not the incremented value. (Also, what Bergi said.)

Comment: Read up on post-increment vs. pre-increment for the exact meaning of i++.  It is working.

Comment: Awesome thanks guys.

Comment: Simplify to `i = (i >= 8 ? 0 : i) + 1;` or `i%=8; i+=1;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263077/why-is-javascripts-postfix-notation-different-from-c-and-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Raymond mentioned, you're using postincrement, you should use preincrement in this context:

```
i = (i >= 8 ? 1 : ++i);
```